# Physics Material slow down the game

Tags: ios, performance, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I have developed game something like coin dozer. And for the smooth movement of coin i have add one Physics Material to each coin but my game is very slow after doing that . Is there any alternative of that or how can i make coin movement smooth without use of Physics material . So can anybody help me to come out from this situation.

Comment: I have some experience in building a coin dozer game with Unity3D. It can hardly be a problem by applying physics material to a gameObject. Physics material is noting more than some math parameters for physics calculation. It is probably the colliders and rigid bodies which cause the issue. Please open profiler and see which parts is the heaviest (if you are using a pro license).  I guess you should use some lighter collider and less calculation itration

Comment: Coin is imported from the 3d studio and it's obj extension. so instead of mesh collider which collider i can you?

Comment: i have see the profiler physics are 94% when dozer pushes to coin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the problem is physics calculation.

DO NOT use the mesh of the graphic as the collider to calculate coin's moving, especially when there are lots of triangles and verts on the mesh. You should choose a simpler collider, maybe something like prism would behavior similar as a coin and reduce a lot of calculation. You can use another simple prism mesh exported from 3d software and make a new game object with that mesh. Stripe off everything related to physics(rigid body, collider and physics material) from the origin coin. Then organize the visible coin without physics and the new added object(which handle all physics) to the same parent. Less triangles in a mesh collider means less calculation. Control the collider mesh triangles as few as possible. I suggest to use a box collider as a start point to check if the performance improves.

Another thing might help is changing the `Solver Iteration Count` in the Physics Setting. You can try to change it to a lower value (maybe 3 or 4 is enough for a coin game) from the default.

Limit the frame rate to a lower value alse can help, but it is the last way you should go.

Comment: you are awesome. Thanks for your reply.After changes in Solver Iteration Count value to 2 now game is bit smooth and i have check the box collider , and with the box collider game is working perfectly. so the problem is mesh collider. can you pleas give me some more information about "prism mesh exported from 3d software" because i am new to unity3d.

Comment: If you have a 3D designer, you can ask him/her to make a prism (3d polygon) like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prism_(geometry)). Maybe 8 edges or 16 edges can describe a coin well. Then you can use the prism mesh as the collider mesh instead of box collider (to improve the reality). If there is not a 3d designer for you, you have to make one yourself. In fact it is enough simple to DIY.

Answer (score 0):

You can add physics to the coins with delay. I mean add physics when coin is near to fall. Also you need to destroy every coin body when you are removing the coin out of the scene.  If you are removing only sprite the there will be too many bodies on the scene.